# How to find out the percentage of intersection between a Rectangle and a Path2D

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make an online game out of an old boardgame called ADAC Simulator. I am trying to create the map with a inner and outer curve using path2d. Is there a way to find out if a certain rectangle is more than 50% in the racetrack (pink area)? If so, is it also possible to paint that rectangle only the part which is inside the track and not the whole rectangle?

Here a picture of the gameboard so far. The red line is a Path2d and the green ones are Rectangle.

[gameboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhOTB.png)

Comment: I suppose you can paint the racetrack, car, and scenery in that order.  The part of the car outside the racetrack will be overpainted by the scenery.

Answer (score 0):

The way to only show the part that is inside the racetrack is to set the clipping value on the graphics object

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  g.setClip(trackPath2D);
  g.setColor(...);
  g.fillRect(...); // also can use graphics2D.fill with the rectangle shape
}
```

I don't know of a way that you could calculate the percentage of the rectangle that fits inside a general path2D